# Hierarchical k-Means in OpenCV without knowledge of "k"

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to cluster a set of 4D vectors, without knowing how many clusters there should be in advance. In the past, I've been able to use cvKmeans2 to cluster, given knowledge of the number of clusters. I was trawling through the API and came across [`cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/flann/doc/flann_clustering.html). This looks like it will do what I need (namely, perform k-means, split clusters where necessary, iterate until splitting worsens the result), but I'm really struggling with the "index parameters".

I've figured out I need to create an [index structure](http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.2/html/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html) which goes in as the second parameter, but I'm getting an error from the following code:

`cv::flann::Index fln_idx = cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams::createIndex( framePoints );`

The error being:

`../src/segmentation_1.cpp:592: error: cannot call member function ‘virtual flann::Index* cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams::createIndex(const cv::Mat&) const’ without object`

`framePoints` is defined as below:

`CvMat *framePoints = cvCreateMat( frameTracklets.size( ), 4, CV_32FC1 );`

I'm fairly sure I'm doing something pretty stupid (my C++ knowledge is ok, but not great). I think I've posted all the relevant bits of code but if not, let me know and I'll post more.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I've followed LumpN's advice and created a Kmeans object, using the following:

```
cv::Mat centres;
cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams fln_idx = cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams();
fln_idx.createIndex( framePoints );

int numClust;
numClust = hierarchicalClustering(framePoints, centres, fln_idx);
```

Now when I run it I get an error message from `hierarchicalClustering()` saying something like "the number of desired clusters should be `>= 1`" (I need to check when I get to work - I'll update then with the actual error). I assumed that the `createIndex()` gave it starting point, then `hierarchicalClustering()` split clusters until a good result was found (not sure if this is optimal or not). Do I need to call `cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams()` with some arguments? I've looked at the api and am thoroughly confused!
Thanks again!

Comment: Worth noticing that `cvflann::HierarchicalClusteringIndex` resembles k-means but is not. It is the implementation of the approach by Muja & Lowe for fast matching of binary features (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6233169) using a forest of hierarchical clustering trees. It is not k-means since there is no iteration step trying to reduce overall distortion as in k-means, i.e. sum of squared distance of the points to its cluster center, and it selects the cluster centers from the data instead taking the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a reference to `createIndex`, i.e. `createIndex(*framePoints)` (note the asterix!). Another error might be `createIndex` being a non-static (member) function. In that case you'd have to create a `KMeansIndexParams` object and call `createIndex` on that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Creating the `KMeansIndexParams` object solved this problem, but now I have another - it says the number of desired clusters must be at least 1. I thought the algorithm was supposed to determine the number of desired clusters?

Answer (score 2):

"number of desired clusters must be at least 1".

Desired cluster count is determinated by centers.rows . So You have to resize centers first.
For Example:

```
Mat centers (clusterCount,DESCRIPTOR_SIZE,cv_32FC1);
int count = cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<cvflann::L2<float> >(descriptors,centers,cvflann::KMeansIndexParams(32,11,cvflann::FLANN_CENTERS_KMEANSPP));
```